# adminhtml form ui_component fields not rendered

Tags: php, adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform, magento2.4.4

I have created a form using ui component. But the form fields are not being rendered in the admin backend, other Save button and left tab is displayed.

The ui_component XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_form.mastering_item_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_form.mastering_item_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
            <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="mastering_item_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Mastering\SampleModule\Ui\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mastering_item_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="collectionFactory" xsi:type="object">Mastering\SampleModule\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="mastering/item/save" />
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">general</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</listing>
```

DataProvider.php

```
    <?php

namespace Mastering\SampleModule\Ui;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $collection;

    public function __construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $collectionFactory, array $meta = [], array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($this->collection->getItems() as $item) {
            $result[$item->getId()] ['general'] = $item->getData();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

[image]